# Perl DBI Results Referenced by Index

Tags: eclipse, perl, eclipse-plugin, dbi, epic

**The Problem:**

I'm using `DBI` with Perl, and need to do a double nest loop through records in my records set.

In the past, I've used while statements like:

```
my $someQuery = "SELECT * FROM foo;";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($someQuery);
$sth->execute();
while (my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    my $someVariable = "$ref->{'dbFieldName'}";
    # do stuff
}
```

What I've trying to achieve would be easy to do with a `for loop` instead of a `while loop`, but I'd need to know how to reference the results by row index as well as the total rowcount. Any idea on how to do this?

**Bonus Points:**

The above will help me solve the one problem, but I'd like to get better techniques to let me figure it out on my own. I'm using Perl EPIC in Eclipse, which doesn't give any sort of context look-ahead/autocomplete (or if it does I don't know how to enable it). Is there a way to enable this or a different add-on for Eclipse that would show the context look-ahead, so I could see what options are available?

Comment: By "row index," do you mean you want 0 for the first row, 1 for the second row, 2 for the third row, etc.?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes and the total number of rows returned.

Comment: I guess I could create my own in array by using the while loop and counting how many records I come across, but I think that would be silly and that there would already be a way to do it.

Comment: Perhaps `fetchall_arrayref({})` as the fourth example [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchall_arrayref)?

Comment: As for better techniques to solve these types of problems on your own: my first recommendation would be to read the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI). Scan the contents, read the synopsis, search for keywords (e.g. "row number", "count"), read about similar methods to the one you're using. Even if you don't find exactly what you're looking for, that should at least give you some additional hints and keywords that you can use in a Google search.

Comment: I am concerned about *why* you want to do a doubly nested loop over your table. The sorts of things you would use that for are generally better left to the database engine to do for you. Please would you explain a little about what you are aiming to achieve.

Comment: @Borodin, My query gets me a list of connection and I need to perform some scripts between every permutation. So a doubly nested loop is appropriate.

Comment: Figured out my issue with `Perl EPIC` in `Eclipse`... seems I had the perl file open by itself, not within a perl project. Once I put it in a perl projec then the autocomplete features started working as well as coding highlights of code problems... guess that portion was a PEBKAC.

Answer (score 1):

## Current row number

There are a couple of ways you can get the row number:

### Perl variable

```
my $row_num = 0;

while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    $row_num++;

    # Do stuff
}
```

### SQL variable

This depends on which DBMS you're using, but you can do something like this in MySQL:

```
$dbh->do('SET @row_num := 0');

my $statement = <<'SQL';
    SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 AS row_num,
           foo,
           bar
    FROM table
SQL

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($statement);
$sth->execute;

while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    say $row->{row_num};

    # Do stuff
}
```

## Total rows returned

You can use [`$sth->rows`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#rows), with the following caveat:

> Generally, you can only rely on a row count after a non-`SELECT` `execute` (for some specific operations like `UPDATE` and `DELETE`), or after fetching all the rows of a `SELECT` statement.
>
> For `SELECT` statements, it is generally not possible to know how many rows will be returned except by fetching them all. Some drivers will return the number of rows the application has fetched so far, but others may return -1 until all rows have been fetched. So use of the rows method or `$DBI::rows` with `SELECT` statements is not recommended.
>
> One alternative method to get a row count for a `SELECT` is to execute a `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ..."` SQL statement with the same "..." as your query and then fetch the row count from that.

However, if you're already counting each row as you fetch it, you could simply use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the *hack* I did to get the results into an array structure, which will allow me to do the nested looping easily. Hopefully someone else will post an answer if they have a better way.

```
my @results;        
my $fieldFirstName = 0;
my $fieldLastName = 1;      
my $fieldAddress = 2;
my $i = 0;

my $someQuery = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address FROM foo;";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($someQuery);
$sth->execute();
while (my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    $results[$i][$fieldFirstName] = "$ref->{'FirstName'}";
    $results[$i][$fieldLastName] = "$ref->{'LastName'}";
    $results[$i][$fieldAddress] = "$ref->{'Address'}";
    $i++;
}
$sth->finish();
my $resultsRecordCount = @results;
```

Comment: This is essentially what Jim Davis's [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990198/perl-dbi-results-referenced-by-index/27991108#comment44372992_27990198) of `fetchall_arrayref({})` does (except more efficiently).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Meaning that the `fetchall_arrayref` solution is more efficient, not this one.

Comment: @Borodin Right. Should have said "less efficiently."